# How can I undo the effects of startx logverbose 6

Tags: graphics, 15.04, xorg

Since running `sudo startx logverbose 6` I can no longer log in to Ubuntu 14.04. Logging in loops back to the login screen. I have seen this problem before when installing incorrect drivers but that isn't the case here.

What might the above command have changed? It was my understanding that it would just list EDID information for my TV/Monitor - I foolishly followed an old tutorial on extracting EDID info.

I am able to log in as normal using a guest account. Ubuntu 15.04 x86

Answer (score 2):

go to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> login and 
run command

```
sudo chown username:groupname ~/.Xauthority
```

generally `groupname` is your `username`

you started X system as root so the file `.Xauthority` in your home directory got owned by the `root`.

comeback <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> or reboot.